# Cascading soft deletes with laravel 4 not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent, soft-delete

I'm attempting to make cascading soft deletes work by overriding each model's `delete()` function, which I think should cascade down from `Project` to `Version` to `Link`, but the problem is it doesn't seem to do that at all. The idea would be that deleting a project would also delete all the versions, which would delete all the links and clear their cached versions, but using `$this->versions()->delete();` doesn't seem to actually call the `delete()` method in the `Version` model.

Any ideas on how to get this working as I expect it to?

```
class Project extends Eloquent {

  protected $softDelete = true;

  public function versions()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Version');
  }

  public function delete()
  {
    $this->versions()->delete();
    return parent::delete();
  }
}

class Version extends Eloquent {

  protected $softDelete = true;

  public function project()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Project', 'project_id');
  }

  public function links()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Link');
  }

  public function delete()
  {
    $this->links()->delete();
    return parent::delete();
  }
}

class Link extends Eloquent {

  protected $softDelete = true;

  public function version()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Version', 'version_id');
  }

  public function delete()
  {
    Cache::forget($this->id);
    return parent::delete();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [models events](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events) instead of overriding the core functions. To quote the docs:

> Eloquent models fire several events, allowing you to hook into various points in the model's lifecycle using the following methods: **creating**, **created**, **updating**, **updated**, **saving**, **saved**, **deleting**, **deleted**, **restoring**, **restored**.

What you want to do is hook into these. You can do this a couple of ways ([see the docs here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events)). Here's an example by setting a model boot method:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    /**
     * Deleting
     * - Called before delete()
     * - Passes the instance in as param
     */
    static::deleting(function($project){
        // Get the project versions ids as an array
        $ids = $project->versions()->lists('id');

        // Delete the versions
        Version::whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();
    });
}
```

You can then do the same in your other models. Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working, and in fact seems to behave like the overridden delete function. When I call the delete from a project, the versions are deleted, but it never gets to the links, and as far as I can tell it never even actually enters the versions `static::deleting` method. Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: It looks like I'm not the only one with this problem: http://laravel.io/forum/03-26-2014-delete-relationschild-relations-without-cascade

Comment: Ah my bad yes you'll need to use a query to delete a collection of relations. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`$this->versions()->delete();` as well as `Version::whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();` does a `delete()` call on a query builder, not the eloquent models, which means model events don't get fired. Instead, you should do:

`foreach($this->versions as $version) { $version->delete(); }`